# How to apply blur effect only outside of a widget?

Tags: image, dart, flutter

I am trying to create a ui for cropping images. I want to apply blur effect outside of the selection area.

[image: blur]

In the picture above, area 1 is the selection area. I want to make it centered when this ui initialized. Then user resizes and moves it on the image. And I will use the latest location and size to crop the image.

Is there any way to achieve this by using widgets? I did this with canvas but I would do it with widgets if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you'd be able to have a "cut out" blur effect in this way without using a canvas like you said.

If I were doing this, I would load the two `Image` widgets in a `Stack`, with the back one being blurred, and the front "selection" area having a draggable `ClipRect` that produces the effect you're looking for. I've done something *slightly* similar in a `Stack` and was able to get what I was aiming for.

Comment: "...ClipRect that produces the effect you're looking for." I don't want to apply any effect on the selection area.

Comment: "The effect you're looking for" is a unblurred selection with a blurred background, right?

Comment: Yeah, is it possible apply "anti-blur" effect on a spesific area or widget?

Comment: ....that is what my answer explained. I don't know that anti-blur is possible. The method I suggested uses two images to fake that effect.

Comment: Yeah I also thought of using two images. Can you detail it more?